# Why are there dinosaurs and prehistoric animals in the opening of season 2?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In the opening of season 2, there are dinosaurs and prehistoric animals there. Why?

[image: Animal Outlines]

Comment: I removed the "answer" on your question. Answer belongs to the "Answer" box. However, since you didn't post it there, I assume the question is protected. So, could you give a link to the question you want to answer?

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest Rule of Cool. There are no dinosaurs or other prehistoric animals in the story, neither anime nor manga. But dinosaurs are damn cool.

If I have to try to find a connection to the series, the theme would be extinction. If all walls would be breached, then humanity would face extinction through titans, right?

Manga spoiler (don't read for more enjoyment of the series): With further manga knowledge, I would reformulate the above answer to

> Humanity inside the walls could face extinction in the near future.